# Could not find or load main class org.logicalcobwebs.cglib.transform.hook

Tags: java, eclipse, cglib

Error Message

[image: this is error message] When I am trying to debug my code in eclipse this error appears.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try [editing the run configuration](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/eclipse/eclipse_run_configuration.htm) in eclipse